Indentation depth not corresponding to json-depth in text to json conversion
I want to use the package bsidhom/rewrite-pdf-outline.py and I noticed when I plug in a text file where the indentation-level drops two levels at once the depth in the json file only drops by one level. For example, if you plug in this text file outline.txt:
Contents 0
1. Chapter 1 1
  1.1. Subchapter 1.1. 2
  1.2 Subchapter 1.2 3
2. Chapter 2 4
  2.1 Subchapter 2.1 5
    2.1.1 Subsubchapter 6
Index 7

with the command:
./text_to_json.py <outline.txt | jq --slurp '.' >outline.json

the resulting outline.json looks like this:
[
  {
    "title": "Contents",
    "dest": 0
  },
  {
    "title": "1. Chapter 1",
    "dest": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "1.1. Subchapter 1.1.",
        "dest": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "1.2 Subchapter 1.2",
        "dest": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "2. Chapter 2",
    "dest": 4,
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "2.1 Subchapter 2.1",
        "dest": 5,
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "2.1.1 Subsubchapter",
            "dest": 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Index",
        "dest": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]

you can see that the entry with the title "Index" is still on the second level inside the json-file while it is at the zero level inside the text file. I suspect the error lies in the following section of the text_to_json.py file:
if not last_indent.startswith(space):
   raise Exception(
      f"invalid de-indentation at line {line_number}")
   while len(last_indent) != len(space):
      # NOTE: We rely on preconditions here to avoid more assertions
      # about stack state.
      indent_stack.pop()
      last_indent = indent_stack[-1]

I have tried rearranging the code in that section with
while indent_stack and len(indent_stack[-1]) > len(space):
  indent_stack.pop()

  # Check if the remaining indentation matches exactly
  if not indent_stack or indent_stack[-1] != space:
     raise Exception(
     f"invalid de-indentation at line {line_number}")

but that didn't change anything.

Please provide code to reproduce the problem. A link to some third party library can be useful, but if the problem is in that code, you need to place all the code needed to reproduce the problem (and not more than that) inside the question. Also make sure to use the correct indentation of the code, as what you quoted has dead code.
